# How do I find a word in a txt file using an input variable in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
key=input("What is your word? ")
ans=open("file.txt","r")
for line in ans:
    for word in line.split():
        if (key) in (word):
            print("Yes")
```

The code works when I write it without the input variable but as soon as I do it comes back saying that the text I entered is not defined.

Comment: You can make it a bit optimized by doing `for key in line.split()`, hoping that the key is some word in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Change `input` to `raw_input` and the code will work as expected. [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) evaluates whatever user enters as Python code where as [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) returns the user input as a string.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, `input()` is not the same as in Python3.  In Python2, `input()` is the same as `eval(raw_input())`.  That is, it converts what the user types into Python code.  When the user types a normal word, Python tries to evaluate it but finds that the variable is not defined.  In Python2, you need to use `raw_input()`, not `input()`.